# Failed to extract tables and data using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to parse yahoo finance webpage using beautifulsoup. I am using python 2.7 and bs4 4.3.2. My final objective is to extract in python all the tabulated data from http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ae?s=PXT.TO. As a start, following code cannot find any table from the url. What am i missing?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ae?s=PXT.TO"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url).read())
table = soup.findAll("table")
print table`
```

Comment: i think it might be `find_all`. And does the  `table` tag exist in `soup`?

Comment: It works if you use `find_all`.

Comment: As far as I can determine, `str(soup)` does not contain a table tag, as the questioner implies, and `soup.find_all("table")` returns an empty list. Am I missing the same things?

Comment: jmunsch and holdenweb, you were right. Soup does not contain "table" tag and that was the question why? Apparently it was a version compatibility issue. Tried on other machine with python 3 and it works beautifully. Also the findAll works well. Anyway, many thanks to all who responded for your time.